# 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, twitter

hiee i m a newbee in feild of python please help..

this is the error wat i m getting

'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

here is my code

```
import json
import urllib
import difflib

def main():
    f1 = open('tweet-stream.json','r')    
    Outputfile =open('newdata6.ods', 'w')
    count = 0

    for line in f1:
        d = json.loads(line)
        lang =  d["user"]["lang"]
        status_count = d["user"]["statuses_count"]
        id1= d['user']['id']
        name=d['user']['location']
        print >>Outputfile,"Language: "+ ','+ lang +','+ "Status_Count" +','+str(status_count)+','+str(id1)+','+str(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

Comment: Which version of Python are using? `print` is a function in 3.x. I changed the tag to python for the moment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544686/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-0-5-ordin/33030458#33030458

Answer (score 2):

A good guide to Unicode in Python is here:
http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Following the guidelines in that presentation will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer,  but try replacing

```
       print >>Outputfile,"Language: "+ ','+ lang +','+ "Status_Count" +','+str(status_count)+','+str(id1)+','+str(name)
```

by

```
    print >>Outputfile,"Language: "+ ','+ lang +','+ "Status_Count" +','+unicode(status_count)+','+unicode(id1)+','+unicode(name)
```

Or even do that:

```
print >>Outputfile, u"Language: ,%s,Status_Count,%s,%s,%s" % (lang, status_count, id1, name)
```

Or even better:

```
text = u"Language: ,%(lang)s,Status_Count,%(count)s,%(id)s,%(name)s\n" % {
      "lang": lang,
      "count": status_count,
      "id": id1,
      "name": name
}

OutputFile.write(text)
```

Also telling us the line of the error would be a good thing. As far as I can tell, there error may happen where you try to convert data to ascii using the "str" function. Most probably, json returns a unicode string and it contains non ascii keywords.

Also on a side note, you should keep variables with lower case. Uppercases are for class name and so on. instead of `Outputfile`, you should write `output_file`