# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, decode

I'm simply trying to decode \uXXXX\uXXXX\uXXXX-like string. But I get an error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430'.decode('utf-8')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm Python newbie. What's a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to **decode** already decoded data?

Comment: The problem is that you are using Python 2, where there is a deceiving `.decode` method available on Unicode strings. Use `python3` and the problem magically goes away, as `u''.decode` would cause `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python is trying to be helpful. You *cannot decode* Unicode data, it is already decoded. So Python first will **encode** the data (using the ASCII codec) to get bytes to decode. It is this implicit encoding that fails.

If you have Unicode data, it only makes sense to **encode** to UTF-8, not decode:

```
>>> print u'\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430'
Ольга
>>> u'\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430'.encode('utf8')
'\xd0\x9e\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0'
```

If you wanted a Unicode value, then using a Unicode literal (`u'...'`) is all you needed to do. No further decoding is necessary.

The same implicit conversion takes place in the other direction; if you tried to encode a bytestring you'd trigger an implicit decoding:

```
>>> u'\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430'.encode('utf8').encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Actually I use `msg = msg + u"@id%s (%s)\n" % (u["id"], u["first_name"].encode('utf8'))
` and `print msg` code. And it gives me an error in `print` clause.

Comment: @SergiiMatrunchyk: That's not what your question was asking about though. Is your terminal or console correctly configured to handle the characters that you are trying to print?

Comment: @SergiiMatrunchyk: also, why are you *encoding* then interpolating into a unicode string? You are putting those values into a `u'...'` unicode object, you should not be encoding the values you are interpolating.

Comment: Depending on what process you are running your string through you might want to clean it up first.

You can do this by quickly running it through encode and decode with:
   `string = string.encode("ascii","ignore")
    string = string.decode("ascii")`

With this the string is "clean" from unwanted chars.

Answer (score 18):

you can set default encoding utf-8.

```
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: Bad idea. It's a nasty, nasty hack for people who don't understand encoding: https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/

Comment: Thanks Alastair McCormack for your suggestion

Comment: Do **not** use this [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) solution. `sys.setdefaultencoding` is removed from the module for a reason, changing the implicit default encoding of Python 2 can break 3rd-party libraries that rely on the normal behaviour.

Comment: Too many attempts and finally this answer saved me! Thanks. :)