# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, utf-8, encode

I have an error caused by a print statement:

```
top_users = [
    {u'first_name': u'\u0425\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0442\u044f', u'last_name': u'\u041a\u0430\u0447\u043c\u0430\u0440', u'id': 1077},
    {u'first_name': u'\u042e\u043b\u0456\u044f', u'last_name': u'\u041d\u0435\u0447\u0438\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0443\u043a', u'id': 1169},
    {u'first_name': u'\u0421\u0432\u0454\u0442\u0456\u043a', u'last_name': u'\u0422\u0438\u0445\u043e\u043d\u0447\u0443\u043a', u'id': 6186},
    {u'first_name': u'Dianka', u'last_name': u'Martyushicheva', u'id': 2450},
    {u'first_name': u'\u041e\u043b\u044c\u0433\u0430', u'last_name': u'\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f', u'id': 2977}
]

msg = u"TOP-5 most active group members:\n"
for u in top_users:
    msg = msg + u"@id%s (%s %s)\n" % (u["id"], u["first_name"], u["last_name"])

print (msg) # Here is an error
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my system, because my terminal can handle the codepoints produced just fine. Your **console or terminal** is misconfigured. What platform are you on?

Comment: From your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544686/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-0-5-ordin) I am guessing you are on Mac. The terminal on OS X is correctly configured, but you are probably using an IDE. What environment are you running the script in?

Comment: Also see https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using Coda for editing

Comment: And are you *running* this code in Coda too?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I'm running it directly in Terminal from bash

Comment: What is the output of the `locale` command (in bash, not Python)? Are you trying to redirect the output at all?

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/uAMHQEpU. No redirect to another programs/bash commands. It just should show me result in terminal.

Comment: Are you redirecting the output? What does `python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding'` print?

Comment: Your locale looks fine. Can you give me the command you type in on the command line, and the *full traceback* of the error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The command above gives UTF-8. To run my script I just use `python ./VKLikers.py`. How to produce full traceback?

Comment: Strangely enough there's no `d0` in the code you listed. What did you leave out?

Comment: There is also 
`# -- coding: utf-8 -- ` line on the top

Comment: The error that Python produces when you run `python ./VKLikers.py`, it starts with `Traceback` and ends with the exception.

Comment: @SergiiMatrunchyk: also, your error message is about **decoding** but printing only **encodes**. Your full traceback would show us what is really happening.

Comment: @MarkRansom: ah, good point. `\u041e` encoded to UTF-8 starts with `\xd0`, as do all the initial Cyrillic characters used for first names here.

Comment: @SergiiMatrunchyk: your title exception shows you are *still triggering implicit decoding* somewhere, but not in the code you posted here.

Comment: Oh.. It seems that your link helped me: wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails. I changed Terminal encoding and it worked. Thanks! You can probably make it as answer..